# What are some things to ensure for a program's security?

Tags: c

I am new to programming. and I wanted to see how I could enhance the efficiency of this program, in terms of conciseness and security.

Also, how can I ensure that the user will not break the program by typing a character or a special symbol when I have asked for a number?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    //Declaring Variables
    float num1, num2;
    int op;
    char ans;

    //Getting the user to choose an option
Again:
    printf("\n\t\tMENU FOR OPERATIONS:\n ");
    printf("\t\t____________________\n\n");

    printf("1. Addition\n");
    printf("2. Subtraction\n");
    printf("3. Multiplication\n");
    printf("4. Division\n");
    printf("5. Modulus\n");
    printf("6. Power Function\n\n");
    printf("Enter the MENU option: ");
    scanf("%d", &op);

    while ( op != 1 && op != 2 && op != 3 && op != 4 && op != 5 && op != 6)
    {
        printf("\nYou entered an invalid MENU option!\n");
        printf("Kindly try again.\n\n");
        printf("Enter the MENU option: ");
        scanf("%d", &op);
    }


    //Getting the numbers from user
    printf("Enter the first number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num1);
    printf("Enter the second number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num2);

    //Implementing a switch statement for processing the input
    switch(op)
    {
    //Case for Addition function
    case 1:
        printf("Result = %.1f\n",  num1 + num2 );
        break;

    //Case for Subtraction function
    case 2:
        printf("Result = %.1f\n", num1 - num2);
        break;

    //Case for Multiplication function
    case 3:
        printf("Result = %.1f\n", num1 * num2);
        break;

    //Case for Division function
    case 4:
        printf("Result = %.1f\n", num1 / num2 );
        break;

    //Case for Modulus function
    case 5:
        printf("Result: %d\n",(int)num1 % (int)num2);
        break;

    //Case for Power Function
    case 6:
        printf("Result: %.1f\n", pow(num1, num2));
        break;

    default:
        printf("You entered an invalid operator!\n\n");
        break;

    }
    //Asking the user if he wants to run the program again
    printf("\nDo you want to continue (Y/N)? ");
    ans = getche();
    ans = toupper(ans);

    //Implementing a while loop to get the user to enter a valid character
    while((ans != 'Y' ) && (ans != 'N'))
    {
        printf("\n\nYou must type a Y or an N!\n");
        printf("Do you want to continue (Y/N)? ");
        ans = getche();
        ans = toupper(ans);
    }

    //Implementing an if statement to ascertain whether the user wants to continue or quit
    if( ans == 'Y')
    {
        system("cls");
        goto Again;      //links the program to the start in case of a YES
    }
    else
    {
        exit(1);              //Successfully exits the program in case of a NO
    }
}
```

Comment: For a "limited" program like this, why not write a `get_input()` function that prompts the user and only returns a string that has been checked to be the right length (often 1) and composed of characters from a limited character set (like "012...9"...). You can do the `atoi()` on that string to get integer values. Save a lot of yadda-yadda testing each field with repeated blocks of code. You'd better guard against "division by zero", too...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Operands are of type `float`, division by zero shouldn't cause a problem. Printing NaN is a perfectly acceptable thing for a calculator to do imo.

Comment: @aulven Thanks for that info. In my past, NaN was "not an option" and the program(s) had to respond another way. Thank you for letting me know `:-)`

Comment: @Fe203 Thank you for that. I haven't started with user-defined functions and pointers yet. I'll update the program once I do.

Comment: @aulven -- [Attempted division by zero leads to undefined behavior.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5p5) Robust code should check for such conditions, and this isn't usually a hardship. Yet most implementations follow IEEE 754, which specifies that fp divide by zero generates +∞ or -∞. These correspond to the macro `INFINITY` defined in `math.h`, and on my linux system they print as `inf` and `-inf`.

Comment: @adabsurdum I though it was a well established standard that any modern system follows. Now that I think of it, it makes sense that it is UB from C's perspective, but even the tiny microcontrollers with no hardware fp support have software functions to support fp arithmetic. I don't see any reason why any system implementing fp arithmetic would omit nans and infinities. Regardless, UB is UB afterall. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Stop using `scanf()` as a user interface function. It is not designed to be used as such, and you can easily found plenty of reasons why. I personally like [this](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html). Use combination of `fgets()` and `sscanf`, if necessary.
2. Yes, in the `ctypes.h`, there are functions like `isalpha` and `isdigit` etc.

Additionally, **do not use** `goto` as a flow control element, ever, as it leads to hard to debug, hard to read, hard to follow through spaghetti code. If your program logic is implemented by `goto`, that almost always means you didn't think enough on it.

As a side note, by convention most C functions return 0 in case of success, and a non-zero value indicating some sort of error. Here, i,t is not much of a problem, but if you find yourself writing a library or such, you will annoy your users.

Comment: What would you suggest using in lieu of goto as a flow control element? Nested while loops? I assumed they would return 1 for success and 0 for failure, thank you for that information.

Comment: @HarisSalam You should use loops, yes. Typically in such applications that repeat in similar ways are structured in the following way, startup and preparation codes run, if any, then it enters a main loop, where the actual program logic resides. Besides, user actions such as exit requests are checked in this loop, which determines whether it continues or terminates. If an exit request is encountered, or a problem has occurred, then loop exits, shutdown preparation codes run, if any, and then program terminates.